# TvOS - UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities issue

Tags: ios, react-native, tvos

I am facing troubles uploading the `tvOS` app to the store. I am getting the following message:

> This bundle is invalid. The key UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities in the
> Info.plist may not contain values that would prevent this application
> from running on any device. Refer to 'Understanding the
> UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key' at
> https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1397/_index.html for
> more information.

Follow bellow my `Info.plist`

[image]

When I read the link informed by XCode, I am not clear about what I must to change to submit the TV App.

I've already checked another questions with the same issue, but not working for me.

Anyone can help me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you may have disabled certain keys for `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities`, like `telephony` or `sms`, in your new build. by re-enabling them, the new bundle should become valid. afaik, there isn't a way to remove these keys now, once you have submitted your app.

Comment: Error code: ITMS-90108

Comment: @kenmistry It's the first upload of the App. It's not in the apple store yet. You've suggested to add `telephony` or `sms` for Apple TV? The device does not have this resources...

Comment: no. I meant to use both of them as an example. These two keys were the cause for invalidating my bundle the other time. So i’ve mentioned them here.